# How Can I Set a Formula to Only Update Once

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm collecting Google Form responses in a sheet, and merging over a variable to keep track of who in my roster has responded.

My issue is I'm having to bring the Form responses into the current sheet with `IMPORTRANGE`, and everyone once and a while, that formula inexplicably returns

> "#REF! Import Range Internal Error"

for up to a few hours before correcting itself. This means my completion tracking isn't working at that time.

Is there a way to set a simple function like `=A2` to only update when text is added, and not if it disappears?

I want a sheet to contain the data in the imported range and add to it as more form responses come in, but also keep all the data if the imported range disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put your `IMPORTRANGE` formula into `IFERROR` eg:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1:A1:B"))
```

this way you will get either values you need or nothing till **`#REF!`** disappears.

Comment: I had no clue you could do that with an IFERROR. Thank you so much!